# Installing Veil-Evasion on kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux

So I have been trying to install veil-evasion for like 2 hours now, and I have watched multiple different tutorials, but It doesn't work for me. Heres what happens: At a certain point in the setup, it opens up a python installation window, here everyone just clicks next, but when i click the "Next" button, it doesnt do anything, it simply doesnt do anything even though i am clicking it. I can still cancel it, but it ruins the installation. I've tried restarting my computer, but it still doesnt work. Heres a screenshot:[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbsYK.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using tab and enter keys to navigate?

Comment: Tried that, It didn't work :(